# What regex produces the result between 2 pattern rows?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-lookarounds

#### Briefly

I am trying to set up Sublime Text 4 to hide regions in code. To do this, I use the AutoFold extension, which can fold code fragments according to specified regular expressions. I need a regex that will give content between 2 lines, where the first one contains `#region` and the last one contains `#endregion`.

#### Closer to the subject:

There is a piece of code:

```lua
-- #region NAME 1
line 1
line 2
-- #endregion

line 3

-- #region NAME 2
line 4
line 5
-- #endregion
```

I want to get the result as shown in the picture

[image: desired result]

For demonstration, I am using 2 regexes
`(?<=-- #region NAME 1)(.|\n)*?(?=-- #endregion)` and
`(?<=-- #region NAME 2)(.|\n)*?(?=-- #endregion)`.

## Question

**What should a regular expression look like that will give the same result?**

#### How I tried:

1. `(?<=-- #region )(.|\n)*?(?=-- #endregion)` gives a similar result, but it hides the region name, which doesn't suit me
2. `(?<=\n)[^$]+` removes the beginning of the line before the first `\n`. It looks like something that, together with step 1, will solve my problem, but I can't put it together in a single expression I tried something like this:: `(?<=-- #region )((?<=\n)[^$]+)(?=-- #endregion)`
3. `^.*#region.*\n` gives a full line containing the region and name, but it is also impossible to compose with item 1  tried something like this: `(?<=(^.*#region.*\n))(.|\n)*?(?=-- #endregion)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the whole line with *-- #region* until the end. Then you can make use of `\K` to clear the match buffer and match until the first occurrence of *-- #endregion*

```
-- #region .+\K[\s\S]*?(?=-- #endregion)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2fScR/1)

Taking newlines into account:

```
-- #region .+\R\K[\s\S]*?\R(?=-- #endregion)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T2fScR/2)